# graphviz: is there a way to disable 1/ subgraph or 2/ labelling?

Tags: label, graphviz, disable, subgraph

Is there a way to disable

1. subgraph(same graph but without clustering)
2. disable/hide labelling of vertex and hedge

without redifining the whole graph?

thanks

P.S: it is for teaching/presentation purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `clusterrank=global` (https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/clusterrank/) should turn off the cluster features.  This can also be with commandline option `'-Gclusterrank=global'`
2. If you are trying to change the *default* labels, try `'-Elabel=""'` and `'-Nlabel=""'`